# The API request from the Vuejs component is executed twice

Tags: mongodb, express, vue.js

I am creating To-do Application using Vuejs, Expressjs, and Mongodb.

I have already written through the New Component with a separate link. This is normal, but I am currently using the New Component by importing it into the Root Component without any additional links.

This works, but the API request is executed twice. (Two articles are written.)

I just imported the component, what's the problem?

I have only sent one request but strangely two responses are flying. (id is different, title and content are the same.)

**frontend/components/TodoForm.vue**

```
<template>
    <form @submit.prevent="create">
      title : <input v-model="todo.title">
      content : <input v-model="todo.content">
      <button v-on:click="create" >Create</button>
    </form>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      todo: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    create: function() {
      this.$http.post('/api/todos/create', this.todo)
      .then(
        (response) => {
          console.log(response.data)
          this.$router.push({name: 'Todo', params: { id: response.data._id }})
        },
        (err) => {
          alert('Error')
        }
      )
      .catch(function (error) {
        alert('error')
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**fromtend/components/TodoList.vue**

```
<template>
  <todo-form/>

  <div class="todos">
    <h1>Todos</h1>
    <div v-for="todo in todos" v-bind:key="todo" class="todo">
      <div>
        <strong>{{todo.title}}</strong>
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'Todo', params: { id: todo._id }}">detail</router-link>
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'Edit', params: { id: todo._id }}">edit</router-link>
        <button type="submit" @click="deleteTodo(todo._id)">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TodoForm from './TodoForm';

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      todos: {}
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.$http.get('/api/todos')
    .then((response) => {
      this.todos= response.data
    })
  },
  components: {
    TodoForm
  },
  methods: {
    deleteTodo (id) {
      const targetIndex = this.todos.findIndex(v => v._id === id)
      this.$http.delete(`/api/todos/${id}`)
      .then((response) => {
        this.todos.splice(targetIndex, 1)
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**backend/api**

```
router.post ('/create', (req, res) => {
  let todo = new Todo({
    title: req.body.title || req.body.todo.title,
    content: req.body.content || req.body.todo.content
  });

  todo.save((err) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
    }
    res.json(todo)
  });
});
```

Comment: Did you try to add the event handling `once` like that `<button v-on:click.once="create" >Create</button>` ?

Comment: I have never used prevent.

Comment: Did it worked ?

Comment: prevent and once were not effective.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to change the following code :

```
<template>
  <form>
    title : <input v-model="todo.title">
    content : <input v-model="todo.content">
    <button v-on:click.once="create" >Create</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

Comment: Ah! I found a problem. I had a create event registered for both form and button. It was my mistake. Thank you for answer.

Comment: @COLEAN, If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.